# Reading a file with fread, but doesn't work properly

Tags: c

I'm having a problem with the `fread()` function.
I have saved three structures(name,roll no,etc) in a file but when I'm going to read the entire structure, it is only displaying the last one structure that 
I have saved. Does it have any compatiblity issue or there is a solution for this? The logic to fread it is:

```
void rfile()
{
  clrscr();
  int n=0;
  FILE *fptr;
  if ((fptr=fopen("test2.rec","rb"))==NULL)
    printf("\nCan't open file test.rec.\n");
  else
  {
    while ( fread(&person[n],sizeof(person[n]),1,fptr)!=1);
    printf("\nAgent #%d.\nName = %s.",n+1,person[n].name);
    printf("\nIdentification no = %d.",person[n].id);
    //printf("\nHeight = %.1f.\n",person[n].height);
    n++;
    fclose(fptr);
    printf("\nFile read,total agents is now %d.\n",n);
  }
}
```

Comment: this "void rfile()" is a function that is called in "main()".

Comment: This is strictly C IO, I removed the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `while ( fread(&person[n],sizeof(person[n]),1,fptr)!=1);` : this will read the file to its end. Hence, the result is that the only `person` that is placed in your array is the last of the file, and it is placed at `n=0`. To correct this, use curly brackets to actually do something in the while loop :

```
void rfile()
{
    clrscr();
    int n=0;
    FILE *fptr;
    if ((fptr=fopen("test2.rec","rb"))==NULL)
        printf("\nCan't open file test.rec.\n");
    else
    {
        while ( fread(&person[n],sizeof(person[n]),1,fptr)==1){//here !
            printf("\nAgent #%d.\nName = %s.",n+1,person[n].name);
            printf("\nIdentification no = %d.",person[n].id);
            //printf("\nHeight = %.1f.\n",person[n].height);
            n++;
        }//there !
        fclose(fptr);
        printf("\nFile read,total agents is now %d.\n",n);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right ! I have missed this one ! I edited and corrected it.